# How to Load a viewController from a Xib file using segue? Swift 5

Tags: storyboard, segue, uicollectionviewcell, xib, swift5

I'm trying to go to from one VC (with implemented Xib file inside) to another VC using a segue.

However, I'm getting an error of

> Cannot find 'performSegue' in scope

This is the class of my xib file:

```
class PetNameInfoCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBAction func takeAPhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "UIImagePickerSegue", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`performSegue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue) is one of `UIViewController`'s methods, so it doesn't work on `UICollectionViewCell`. Instead, you'll need to call `performSegue` from the parent view controller that contains the collection view.

You can use delegates or closures for this, but I prefer closures. First, add one inside `PetNameInfoCollectionViewCell`:

```
class PetNameInfoCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var photoTapped: (() -> Void)? /// here!

    @IBAction func takeAPhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
        photoTapped?() /// call it
    }
}
```

Then, assign the closure inside the parent view controller's `cellForItemAt`.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: userNameInfoCollectionViewCellId, for: indexPath) as! userNameInfoCollectionViewCell /// replace with the cell class
        cell.photoTapped = { [weak self] in
            self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "UIImagePickerSegue", sender: nil)
        }
        return cell
        
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PetNameInfoCollectionViewCell, for: indexPath) as! PetNameInfoCollectionViewCell /// replace with the cell class
        cell.photoTapped = { [weak self] in
            self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "UIImagePickerSegue", sender: nil)
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey ,Thank you for your answer!
I'm using the cellForItemAt method for changing the cells in my collectionView like this:
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: userNameInfoCollectionViewCellId, for: indexPath)
        } else {
            return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PetNameInfoCollectionViewCell, for: indexPath)
        }
    }
how I can add the closure inside?

Comment: @Swifty_Man edited my answer. You'll need to do `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell` to get a reference to the cell. Then, after you've configured the `photoTapped`, you can `return` it.

Comment: Yay! it Worked, I spent tons of times to do it with the delegate pattern but from unobvious reason it didn't work for me.
Thank you VERY much!

Comment: Ok, I learned now how to use both with closure and delegates!